# Singleton with arguments using AtomicReference

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton, atomicreference

I have to create a Singleton which takes input arguments . Basically I need to create a DBConnector in a library based on some configuration . Now this configuration is passed to the library by the consuming app . Based on the passed in configuration , I want to create an instance of DBConnector which then would be reused in the library .
I thought of using DI to handle this , but when this library is initialized I dont know if a DB connection is actually required , and I do not want to create this DBConnector if it is not required . 
Once library is initialized, on a getResponse(RequestType rt) call do I come to know if a DBConnector is required (based on RequestType) and that is when I need to create an instance .
Thus the below code look good for a multiThreaded environment ?

```
public class DBConnectorFactory
{
private static volatile DBConnector dBConnector = null;
private static AtomicReference<DBConnector> atomicReference = new AtomicReference<>();
private DBConnectorFactory()
{}

public static DBConnector getDBConnector(DBConfig dBConfig)
{
    if(dBConnector == null)
    {
        if(atomicReference.compareAndSet(null,new DBConnector(dBConfig)))
            dBConnector = atomicReference.get();
        return atomicReference.get();
    }

    else
        return dBConnector;
}
```

}

**EDIT**
Wrote a multithreaded test and all the threads are getting the same instance . However just want to make sure I am not missing out on any edge cases due to Java Memory Model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As is, it looks logically sound to me.

One thing I find intriguing is your use of a singleton pattern that might throw away an instance of `DBConnector` if you lose a race and resort to using a second `AtomicReference#get()`. Isn't the entire point of a singleton to ensure that only a single instance is *ever* created? If this was your intention, then the pattern you are using is not suited for this. You must synchronize.

Otherwise, if you insist on using lock-free initialization and potentially have multiple instantiations, you you should just use a single AtomicReference, like so:

```
private static AtomicReference<DBConnector> instance = new AtomicReference<>();

public static DBConnector getDBConnector(DBConfig dBConfig) {
    // First try
    DBConnector con = instance.get();
    if (con == null) {
        con = // ...

        if (instance.compareAndSet(null, con)) {
            // Successful swap, return our copy
            return con;
        } else {
            // Lost the race, poll again
            return instance.get():
        }
    }

    // Already present value
    return con;
}
```